# Java Time API Locale (week of the year)

Tags: java, time, java-time

Howto pass a localization to the new Java Time API?

In this simple example i try to print current week-of-the-year but the result is always wrong.

```
import java.text.*;
import java.time.*;
import java.time.format.*;
import java.util.*;

//wrong result
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy ww");
System.out.println(LocalDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("Europe/Berlin")).format(formatter));

//this works
System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy ww",Locale.GERMANY).format(new Date()));
```

Comment: What is wrong about the result that you get? I get 2016 29 in both cases, (which is, as far as I can tell, correct).

Comment: There are two DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern methods.  [One of them takes a Locale.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ofPattern-java.lang.String-java.util.Locale-)

Comment: Try DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy ww",Locale.GERMANY);

Comment: @davida. i got 30 (time api) and 29(util.date), my system locale isnt set to germany.

Comment: this worked ´DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy ww",Locale.GERMANY);´

Comment: What is the point of using LocalDateTime.now() if your pattern does not include time ? Could simply use LocalDate.now().

Comment: **Beware:** Your  lowercase `yyyy` (for calendar-year) should be uppercase `YYYY` for week-based-year. See [my Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49838733/642706) for details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass the Locale to ofPattern method of [DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html)

```
 DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy ww",Locale.GERMANY);
 System.out.println(LocalDateTime.now().format(formatter));
```

Comment: **Bad format:** Shows week with calendar-year (`yyyy`) rather than week-based-year (`YYYY`). See [my Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49838733/642706) for explanation and correct code.

Comment: It all depends on what OP has asked. He had accepted this answer, which means it has resolved his issue. Moreover there is a link of Java Doc which has more information.

Comment: The answer from @BasilBourque offers a correct and more complete explanation.

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

Use proper formatting pattern, case-sensitive: `"YYYY ww"`.

```
LocalDate.now( ZoneId.of( "Europe/Berlin" ) )    // Get the current date (date-only value) as seen in the wall-clock time used by the people of a certain region (a time zone).
.format(                                         // Generate a string representing the week and week-based-year according to a particular locale’s definition of ‘week’.
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "YYYY ww" ).withLocale( Locale.GERMANY )
)
```

## `yyyy ww` is invalid

The `yyyy` coding in *java.time* means calendar-year. Following that with `ww` for a week number of a standard ISO 8601 week-based year is misleading and nonsensical.

**You should be combining week-number with *week-based-year* number rather than *calendar-year* number**. The formatting code for that is uppercase `YYYY`. So you would want `YYYY ww`.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "YYYY ww" ) ;
```

## Locale affects `YYYY` not `yyyy`

Since `yyyy` lowercase means calendar year, specifying a `Locale` has no effect. Use `YYYY` uppercase, as mentioned above, if you want the locale-defined week-based-year.

For more info, see the Question: [*Java Time's week-of-week-based-year pattern parsing with DateTimeFormatter*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39584350/642706)

```
Locale locale = Locale.GERMANY ;
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "YYYY ww" ).withLocale( locale ) ;
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.now( ZoneId.of( "Europe/Berlin" ) ) ; // Or "Africa/Tunis", "Pacific/Auckland" etc. Time zone is unrelated (orthogonal) to locale.
String output = ld.format( f ) ;
```

## Standard week

Perhaps you want the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard [definition of week](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date) rather than a locale-defined definition. This is where week # 1 contains the first Thursday of the calendar year, and starts on a Monday, for a total of 52 or 53 weeks per year.

ISO 8601 defines a standard format for week-based year & week. You may want to consider using the standard format rather than your custom format.

Standard format is yyyy-Www for the year-week, and yyyy-Www-d to also  display the day-of-week number where 1-7 is Monday-Sunday. For example, `2012-W48-6` is 2012-12-01, a Saturday (day-of-week # 6).

The `DateTimeFormatter` class comes with a predefined format for this, [`DateTimeFormatter.ISO_WEEK_DATE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_WEEK_DATE).

```
String input = "2012-W48-6";
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( input , DateTimeFormatter.ISO_WEEK_DATE );
System.out.println( ld );
```

> 2012-12-01

You can generate such a string.

```
String output = ld.format( DateTimeFormatter.ISO_WEEK_DATE );
```

> 2012-W48-6

If you want the entire week, without the day-of-week, just truncate the string.

```
String output = ld.format( DateTimeFormatter.ISO_WEEK_DATE ).substring( 0 , 8 ) ;
```

> 2012-W48

## `YearWeek`

If you will be doing much of this work at all, I suggest adding the [*ThreeTen-Extra*](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) library to your project. That library offers many handy classes, one of which is [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html) to represent the standard ISO 8601 week as a whole.

```
YearWeek yw = YearWeek.parse( "2012-W48" ) ;
```

Get the current week.

```
YearWeek yw = YearWeek.now( ZoneId.of( "Europe/Berlin" ) )
```

> yw.toString(): 2012-W48

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), and later
- Built-in.
- Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
- Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)
- Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))
- Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
- For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).