# DateTimeFormatter week-based-year diff

Tags: java, datetime, java-8, java-time, dayofweek

I'm migrating my application from Joda-Time to the Java 8 `java.time`.

One of the things I ran into is the printing of a week-based-year using a pattern in the [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#patterns).

NOTE: I have seen this question: 
[Java Time's week-of-week-based-year pattern parsing with DateTimeFormatter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39584350/java-times-week-of-week-based-year-pattern-parsing-with-datetimeformatter)

According to the documentation

```
y       year-of-era                 year              2004; 04
Y       week-based-year             year              1996; 96
```

Yet when I try these two it seems the `Y` is always returning the same as `y`.

My testing code:

```
DateTimeFormatter yearF = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy").withZone(ZoneOffset.UTC);
DateTimeFormatter weekYearF = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("YYYY").withZone(ZoneOffset.UTC);

DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    .appendValue(ChronoField.YEAR_OF_ERA)   .appendLiteral(" ") .append(yearF)
    .appendLiteral(" -- ")
    .appendValue(IsoFields.WEEK_BASED_YEAR) .appendLiteral(" ") .append(weekYearF)
    .toFormatter()
    .withZone(ZoneOffset.UTC);

System.out.println(dateTimeFormatter.toString());

ZonedDateTime dateTime = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.ofEpochMilli(946778645000L), ZoneOffset.UTC);
for (int i = 2000 ; i < 2020; i ++ ) {
    System.out.println(dateTime.withYear(i).format(dateTimeFormatter));
}
```

The output:

```
Value(YearOfEra)' '(Value(YearOfEra,4,19,EXCEEDS_PAD))' -- 'Value(WeekBasedYear)' '(Localized(WeekBasedYear,4,19,EXCEEDS_PAD))
2000 2000 -- 1999 2000
2001 2001 -- 2001 2001
2002 2002 -- 2002 2002
2003 2003 -- 2003 2003
2004 2004 -- 2004 2004
2005 2005 -- 2004 2005
2006 2006 -- 2006 2006
2007 2007 -- 2007 2007
2008 2008 -- 2008 2008
2009 2009 -- 2009 2009
2010 2010 -- 2009 2010
2011 2011 -- 2010 2011
2012 2012 -- 2012 2012
2013 2013 -- 2013 2013
2014 2014 -- 2014 2014
2015 2015 -- 2015 2015
2016 2016 -- 2015 2016
2017 2017 -- 2017 2017
2018 2018 -- 2018 2018
2019 2019 -- 2019 2019
```

Looking at the years where it matters (like 2000, 2005, 2009 and 2016) the output of `.appendValue(IsoFields.WEEK_BASED_YEAR)` and `.ofPattern("YYYY")` are different.

In [Java Time's week-of-week-based-year pattern parsing with DateTimeFormatter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39584350/java-times-week-of-week-based-year-pattern-parsing-with-datetimeformatter) it is stated that this has to do with the localization (as can be clearly seen as a difference in the `toString()` of the `DateTimeFormatter`).

Now there are few things I do not understand/need:

1. So the 'week-based-year' varies with the Locale, fine. Yet what I do not understand that apparently in some Locales the week-base-year is always identical to the 'normal' year. Why is that?
2. Why hasn't the parsing of the `YYYY` been mapped to the ISO-8601 definition instead of the (terribly confusing!) Localized form.
3. Where can I find proper documentation of this? The apparent 'official' documentation from Oracle is vague to say the least. 
   **Answer**: I found much more extensive documentation with the
   [DateTimeFormatterBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html#appendPattern-java.lang.String-).

Comment: For your first question, 02-01-2000 is still in week 52 of year 1999. Which gives you back 1999. Same for 2005 and 2016.

Comment: @YoshuaNahar: What I meant is that I expect the year and week-based-year to be different every few years. I am surprised that apparently in some Locales there is no difference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The **week-based-year** field, according to [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/WeekFields.html), depends on 2 things: what's the first day of the week, and the minimum number of days in the first week.

The ISO standard defines Monday as the first day of the week, and a minimum of 4 days in the first week:

```
System.out.println(WeekFields.ISO.getFirstDayOfWeek()); // Monday
System.out.println(WeekFields.ISO.getMinimalDaysInFirstWeek()); // 4
```

*(`WeekFields.ISO.weekBasedYear()` is equivalent to `IsoFields.WEEK_BASED_YEAR`, with [minor differences regarding another calendar systems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22874374/what-is-the-motivation-for-two-different-week-based-year-definitions-in-jsr-310#comment35229416_23031415))*

Considering, for example, January 2<sup>nd</sup> 2009, which was a Friday. Checking the [javadoc for the **week-based-year** field](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/WeekFields.html#weekBasedYear--):

> Week one(1) is the week starting on the getFirstDayOfWeek() where there are at least getMinimalDaysInFirstWeek() days in the year. Thus, week one may start before the start of the year.

Considering ISO definition (week starts on Monday, and minimum days in first week is 4), week 1 starts on December 29<sup>th</sup> 2008 and ends in January 4<sup>th</sup> 2009 (that's the first week that starts on a Monday and it has at least 4 days in 2009), so January 2<sup>nd</sup> 2009 has a **week-based-year** equals to 2009 (with ISO definition):

```
// January 2st 2009
LocalDate dt = LocalDate.of(2009, 1, 2);
System.out.println(dt.get(WeekFields.ISO.weekBasedYear())); // 2009
System.out.println(dt.get(WeekFields.ISO.weekOfWeekBasedYear())); // 1
// WeekFields.ISO and IsoFields are equivalent
System.out.println(dt.get(IsoFields.WEEK_BASED_YEAR)); // 2009
System.out.println(dt.get(IsoFields.WEEK_OF_WEEK_BASED_YEAR)); // 1
```

But if I consider a `WeekFields` instance for [`en_MT` locale (English (Malta))](http://www.localeplanet.com/icu/en-MT/index.html), the first day of week is Sunday, and the minimum number of days in first week is 4:

```
WeekFields wf = WeekFields.of(new Locale("en", "MT"));
System.out.println(wf.getFirstDayOfWeek()); // Sunday
System.out.println(wf.getMinimalDaysInFirstWeek()); // 4
System.out.println(dt.get(wf.weekBasedYear())); // 2008
System.out.println(dt.get(wf.weekOfWeekBasedYear())); // 53
```

The first week that starts on a Sunday and has at least 4 days in 2009 is the week from January 4<sup>th</sup> to 10<sup>th</sup>. So, according to the week definition for `en_MT` locale, January 2<sup>nd</sup> 2009 belongs to the **53<sup>th</sup> week** of the **week-based-year** 2008.

Now, if I take the [`ar_SA` locale (Arabic (Saudi-Arabia))](http://www.localeplanet.com/java/ar-SA/index.html), the week starts on Saturday, and the minimum number of days in first week is 1:

```
WeekFields wf = WeekFields.of(new Locale("ar", "SA"));
System.out.println(wf.getFirstDayOfWeek()); // Saturday
System.out.println(wf.getMinimalDaysInFirstWeek()); // 1
System.out.println(dt.get(wf.weekBasedYear())); // 2009
System.out.println(dt.get(wf.weekOfWeekBasedYear())); // 1
```

For this locale, week 1 starts in December 27<sup>th</sup> 2008 and ends in January 2<sup>nd</sup> 2009 (it's the first week that starts on a Saturday and has at least 1 day in 2009). So, the **week-based-year** for January 2<sup>nd</sup> 2009 in `ar_SA` locale is also 2009 (the same value I've got using `IsoFields`, **even though the week definition is completely different from ISO**).

---

While `IsoFields.WEEK_BASED_YEAR` uses ISO's definition, the pattern `YYYY` will use the `WeekFields` instance corresponding to the locale set in the formatter (or the JVM default locale, if none is set).

Depending on the definition of each locale (first day of week and minimum number of days in first week), the **week-based-year** from the localized pattern (`YYYY`) might have the same value (or not) of the ISO field.

Although it sounds strange that a week can start or end in another year, the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/WeekFields.html) says that it's perfectly valid:

> The first and last weeks of a year may contain days from the previous calendar year or next calendar year respectively.

---

The pattern letters of `java.time` [were based on CLDR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41177442/uuuu-versus-yyyy-in-datetimeformatter-formatting-pattern-codes-in-java#comment69566655_41177442) (The [Unicode Common Locale Data Repository](http://cldr.unicode.org/)). [This link about Week based patterns](http://cldr.unicode.org/translation/date-time-patterns#TOC-Week-Of-Patterns) says:

> The year indicated by Y typically begins on the **locale**’s first day of the week and ends on the last day of the week

Anyway, CLDR is all about localization, so `Y` is localized as well - as stated by [Stephen Colebourne's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46389117/datetimeformatter-week-based-year-diff/46395342#comment79764940_46395342) below:

> The whole purpose of CLDR is localization, so yes, the "Y" pattern letter is localized. While I understand the desire for a pattern letter that always operates using the ISO rules, it doesn't exist and getting CLDR to add it would be hard to impossible. (Java is following CLDR closely)

---

My conclusion is, if you want ISO week fields, don't use the localized patterns. Or, as a - not ideal, quite ugly - workaround, use a locale that matches ISO's week definition (in my JVM, `Locale.FRENCH` does the trick, as `WeekFields.ISO.equals(WeekFields.of(Locale.FRENCH))` returns `true`). The only problem is that the locale will also affect other fields (in case you have month or day of week names, such as `MMM` or `EEE`, and any other locale sensitive data).

Comment: The whole purpose of CLDR is localization, so yes, the "Y" pattern letter is localized. While I understand the desire for a pattern letter that always operates using the ISO rules, it doesn't exist and getting CLDR to add it would be hard to impossible. (Java is following CLDR closely). The key here however is that unlike Java 7, a formatter can be created that can handle this use case via `DateTimeFormatterBuilder`.

Comment: @JodaStephen I've updated the answer (quoting your comment, if you don't mind). Thanks a lot!

Comment: Tip: If indeed standard [ISO 8601 weeks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date) are desired, see the [*ThreeTen-Extra*](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project for its [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html) class.