# Failed to parse single digit hour and lowercase am-pm of day into Java 8 LocalTime

Tags: datetime, java-8, java-time, localtime, datetime-parsing

When I try to run the following code:

```
LocalTime test = LocalTime.parse("8:00am", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("hh:mma"));
```

I get this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '8:00am' could not be parsed at index 0
```

Any idea why this might be happening?

Comment: What happens if you use just a single `h`, like `"h:mma"`?

Answer (score 8):

`AM/PM` pattern is locale sensitive. If you create a formatter and don't set a `java.util.Locale`, it'll use the JVM's default. Anyway, I've checked in JDK 1.8.0_144 and there's no locale that uses lowercase `am` as the text for `AM/PM` field (I've found locales that use `a.m.` and `AM`, but no `am`).

So, one alternative is to set a locale that uses `AM` (example: `Locale.ENGLISH`) and use a `java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder` to build a **case insensitive** formatter. Another detail is that the hour in the input has only 1 digit, so you must change the pattern to `h` (which accepts 1 or 2 digits, while `hh` accepts only 2):

```
DateTimeFormatter fmt = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    // case insensitive
    .parseCaseInsensitive()
    // pattern
    .appendPattern("h:mma")
    // set Locale that uses "AM" and "PM"
    .toFormatter(Locale.ENGLISH);
// now it works
LocalTime test = LocalTime.parse("8:00am", fmt);
```

The problem is that the locale can also affect other fields (if you use month or day of week names, or [week based fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46389117/datetimeformatter-week-based-year-diff), for example).

Another detail is that the formatter is case insensitive only for parsing. When formatting, it'll use the locale specific symbols, which in this case is uppercase. So this:

```
System.out.println(fmt.format(test)); // 8:00AM
```

Prints:

> 8:00AM

---

To not depend on the locale, you can use a map of custom texts for this field, using a `java.time.temporal.ChronoField`:

```
// map of custom text for AM/PM field
Map<Long, String> map = new HashMap<>();
// AM's value is 0
map.put(0L, "am");
// PM's value is 1
map.put(1L, "pm");
DateTimeFormatter fmt = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    // pattern (hour:minute)
    .appendPattern("h:mm")
    // use custom text for AM/PM
    .appendText(ChronoField.AMPM_OF_DAY, map)
    // create formatter, no need to set locale
    .toFormatter();
// it also works
LocalTime test = LocalTime.parse("8:00am", fmt);
```

The difference from the previous formatter is that it uses the custom text (lowercase `am` and `pm`) for both parsing and formatting. So this code:

```
System.out.println(fmt.format(test)); // 8:00am
```

Will print:

> 8:00am

Answer (score 7):

The AM/PM tokens have* to be uppercase:

```
LocalTime test = LocalTime.parse("8:00AM", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("hh:mma"));
```

Patterns definitions for hours:

```
Symbol  Meaning                     Presentation      Examples
------  ------------                ------------      --------
a       am-pm-of-day                text              PM
h       clock-hour-of-am-pm (1-12)  number            12
K       hour-of-am-pm (0-11)        number            0
k       clock-hour-of-am-pm (1-24)  number            0
H       hour-of-day (0-23)          number            0
```

Refer to the `DateTimeFormatter` javadocs for all available patterns: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html

-- EDIT

*As per @Hugo's comment, this is related to the [Locale](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) your formatter is setup on. If you are not specifying any, then the JVMs default is used. It just happens that the vast majority of Locales enforces AM/PM tokens to be upper case:

> It so happens that, for most locales, the uppercase AM is used, so it'll work for most people. But it can also be a.m. in ga_IE and es_US locales, 午前 in Japanese (ja_JP), fm in Swedish (sv_SE), and many others. I've tested in JDK 1.8.0_144 and it has 160 locales - 108 of them use AM - anyway, it's not an issue if your JVM uses one of those 108 locales (and nobody changes this config)

Comment: Actually, it doesn't *have* to be uppercase (the javadoc shows just an example), it all depends on the locale (when you create a formatter without specifying a locale, it uses the JVM's default). It so happens that, for most locales, the uppercase `AM` is used, so it'll work for most people. But it can also be `a.m.` in ga_IE and es_US locales, `午前` in Japanese (ja_JP), `fm` in Swedish (sv_SE), and many others. I've tested in JDK 1.8.0_144 and it has 160 locales - 108 of them use `AM` - anyway, it's not an issue if your JVM uses one of those 108 locales (and nobody changes this config)

Comment: @Hugo Wonderful addition, I honestly didn't know that. I will include your info on the answer. Thanks!

Comment: [Never use `SimpleDateFormat` or `DateTimeFormatter` without a `Locale`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65544056/10819573).

Answer (score 2):

AM/PM are uppercase, and you need to use `h` to specify one digit for hours (with `hh` two digits are required). Like,

```
LocalTime test = LocalTime.parse("8:00am".toUpperCase(), 
        DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("h:mma"));
```

Comment: I believe this is the key point of the question. If you use ONE `h` you need to specify ONE digit, otherwise, use TWO `hh` for TWO digits.

Answer (score 1):

You need to capitalize to AM and add a leading zero in front of the 8.

```
LocalTime lt=LocalTime.parse("08:00AM",DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("hh:mma"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a heads up, In Adelaide the requirement is for it to use am insteam of AM, so I am having to .toLowerCase() my dates prior to parsing from text.  So "AM" fails, "am" works.

Answer (score 0):

```
LocalTime lt=LocalTime.parse("08:00p.m.",DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("hh:mma"));
```

if you put a.m. or p.m. it works but AM or PM not working. 
i am using  openjdk 11 and openjdk 14, i think it is a bug.