# how to convert from 10-JUN-02 01.57.07.848594000 PM to yyyy-MM-dd-HH24.MI.SS.FF6 in java

Tags: java, datetime-format, datetime-parsing

how to convert from 10-JUN-02 01.57.07.848594000 PM to    yyyy-MM-dd-HH24.MI.SS.FF6 in java

Comment: So, your basic question is how to convert a `String` to a date/time value and then format it to another `String` - both questions are relatively common and have been asked and answered may times before. I might suggest starting with [Date and Time Classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/datetime.html) and [Java string to date conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216745/java-string-to-date-conversion) as a starting point of your research

Comment: i have done it with oracle but never with java

Comment: You have to recognise that while you might not have done, many other people before you have.  It's not an uncommon problem. I will, however, give you some leeway as the input is unusual

Comment: What does `HH24.MI.SS.FF6` mean? Are you trying to truncate the nanoseconds to microseconds?

Answer (score 4):

Start by taking a look at

- [Date and Time Classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/datetime.html)
- [Java string to date conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216745/java-string-to-date-conversion)
- [Failed to parse single digit hour and lowercase am-pm of day into Java 8 LocalTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46480520/failed-to-parse-single-digit-hour-and-lowercase-am-pm-of-day-into-java-8-localti)

You question is not unique nor uncommon and some due diligence in researching your issue will be more highly rewarded.

You basic question is actually two questions:

- How to parse a `String` to a date/time object
- How to format a date/time object

I appreciate that in this day and age there are at least 3 distinct methods you might approach these problems.  However, the Date/Time API introduced in Java 8 should be your preferred approach.

Having said that, you will probably have two major stumbling blocks in getting something to work.

Both relate to the uncommon case of your input (`JUN` and `pm`).

Java 8 introduced the `DateTimeFormatterBuilder` class which can be used to overcome this issue.

```
DateTimeFormatter dtf = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
        .parseCaseInsensitive()
        .appendPattern("dd-MMM-yy hh.mm.ss.SSSSSSSSS a")
        .toFormatter(Locale.ENGLISH);

LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse("10-JUN-02 01.57.07.848594000 pm", dtf);
```

This will provide you with a date/time representation of your input.

Then, you just need another `DateTimeFormatter` to format the output as desired...

```
DateTimeFormatter output = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd-HH.mm.ss.SSSSSS", Locale.ENGLISH);
System.out.println(output.format(ldt));
```

which outputs...

```
2002-06-10-13.57.07.848594
```

Make sure you have a read through the [JavaDocs for `DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) to better understand the formatter specifications

Comment: @kari if that’s important to you, then use an Instant instead of LocalDateTime. You’ll also forgive me if I don’t understand your comment, as the date/time api supports daylight savings